How is 'How did the Gospel writers know that Mary was a virgin?' opinion based?
Opinion is usually like 'who's your favourite apostle?' not 'who did mary x joseph 1st tell about the virgin birth?'
I think it's reasonable to ask ... like

Did Mary x Joseph tell Jesus but then they kept it a family secret for awhile? Maybe including the inner circle (disciples, apostles, John the Baptist, Mary Magdalene & other close friends/family of Jesus) ? And then they just waited until after the Ascension to say something?
Or did they go around telling everyone at the start?

I mean, what's the factual way to ask any of the above?
There's actually a part where Michael L Brown in 'Jewish Objections to Jesus' says


The fact of the virgin birth was something that made the ministry of Jesus harder, not easier.

Since ministry means

The ministry of Jesus, in the canonical gospels, begins with his baptism near the River Jordan by John the Baptist, and ends in Jerusalem in Judea, following the Last Supper with his disciples.

Oh ok so apparently it was already somewhat known but I guess inner circle before ultimately revealing to the world and then recording in the Gospels.
But anyway the point is I don't think it's opinion-based or that it can be modified somehow to not be opinion-based.

The Meta site is for questions about how the main site SE-Christianity operates and is Moderated.

Dogma, as Chesterton acutely points out - and I've quoted here ad nauseum - is just the Greek for opinion.  So a question here is often closed as opinion based as a shorthand as a request to narrow down the question to a certain faith tradition or perspective.
I would prefer it if people would close questions with the other close reason - "opinion based" is a generic close reason that all stackexchange sites have.  It exists because people would ask questions about the most comfortable chair for programming on stackoverflow and the powers that be decided fun questions were not real questions back well over a decade ago.

You can ask in those various ways you have described. None of those are opinion as they deal with the Christian early tradition of the inner circle (disciples) and the interpretation of those certain passages, concerning the knowledge of the alleged virgin birth of Jesus. It is a question of theology as well as history concerning the virgin birth narrative. Michael Brown is a traditional or fundamentalist scholar and mainly dealing the issue from a theological angle. I recommend you the book by Andrew Lincoln: Born of a Virgin?
